# почему регулярное выражение всегда true?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Пытаюсь сделать проверку при вставке в поле input. Но тест регулярного выражения всегда выдает true, в не зависимости от того что пишешь\вставляешь. Пишешь: Вася - True, Vasya - True. Почему так? Флаги не влияют на результат

```
textInputs.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('input', function () {
                console.log(/[^A-z]*$/ig.test(this.value));
           
        });
    })
```

Comment: Добавьте вывод в консоль this.value

Comment: зачем чтобы проверить работает ли this.value? Проверял, работает

Comment: Так что в итоге регулярное выражение должно находить? Почитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения] — надо привести однозначное описание

Comment: 1) Что вы хотите проверить этим регулярным выражением? 2) Чему соответствует `this`?

Answer (score 4):

`*` указывает, что может быть **0** или больше повторений.

Таким об разом - отсутствие нужных символов в конце строки - допускается.

Если требуется, чтобы было 1 или больше - то следует использовать `+`